# How can i lookup the imap setting by using Javascript of any Gmail,outlook,yahoo account

Tags: smtp, gmail, imap, multimap, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to lookup the Imap setting of any gmail,outlook, yahoo account by using javascript ...Like server Hostname, server port, SSL/TLS, and so on...and auto fetch the IMAP setting of the account first and then as for password...in my email client web app

Comment: Very open-ended question. I could write for an hour and perhaps not even answer the part you're really wondering about. Please refine the question, and add enough detail that we understand some precise thing you want to do.

Comment: I am trying to look my gmail account IMAP setting by Javascript  for login authorization in my own email webapp

Comment: If it's gmail, just hardcode it.  If it's any server anywhere, you have to guess and try, borrow [Mozilla's ISP Database](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration) or ask the user.

Comment: No No It may be Gmail, outlook,yahoo etc...then how can i fetch the imap setting of any account out only using Username only...